# Best way to implement MPMoviePlayer timeout

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I have MPMoviePlayer that load movie from stream. I implemented timeout on 15 seconds with timers. But is there maybe some other better way to implement timeout without timer?

Answer (score 0):

Register for the `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification`. Within its handler, check the current loadstate and mask out the `MPMovieLoadStateStalled`.

```
- (void)MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //is the player stalled, hence possibly starving?
    if ((movieController_.loadState & MPMovieLoadStateStalled) == MPMovieLoadStateStalled)
    {  //yes->do something
       NSLog(@"hey there, I am starving to death here");
    }
}
```

You may want to register a timer within the upper if-clause - e.g. 10seconds. Once that baby runs out of time without further state-changes, do something to terminate / skip the video playback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think it's possible to use `performSelector` as timer?

```
[self performSelector:@selector(checkTimeout:) withObject:theMovie afterDelay:15];
```

and then check for the movie state.