# MPMoviePlayerController Bad Url Error

Tags: ios

If I give MPMoviePlayerViewController a bad video URL to play, like so:

```
[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://badurl"]];
```

Is there a way to be notified that the video did not download?

I tried both of the following, but was not notified in either case:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadStateChanged) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: This used to work in iOS 7 but stopped working in iOS 8. I have an open bug with Apple but they have done nothing about it. I ended up using a timer which is a terrible design but the only solution that works.

Comment: Yeah, using iOS 8.1 and my MPMoviePlayer.url is getting 404 error, but it's not triggering the [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all check if URL is reachable using `Rechability`.

```
 NSURL *myURL = [NSURL urlWithString: @"http://example.com"];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: myURL];
 [request setHTTPMethod: @"HEAD"];
 dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, NULL), ^{
      NSURLResponse *response;
      NSError *error;
      NSData *myData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: &response error: &error];
      BOOL reachable;

      if (myData) {
            // we are probably reachable, check the response
            reachable=YES;
      } else {
            // we are probably not reachable, check the error:
            reachable=NO;
      }

      // now call ourselves back on the main thread
      dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self setReachability: reachable];
      });
 });
```

its mention is this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9617166/1721884)

or

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];


- (void) playbackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification{
    NSNumber* reason = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];
switch ([reason intValue]) {
    case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded:
        NSLog(@"Playback Ended");         
        break;
    case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError:
        NSLog(@"Playback Error"); //// this include Bad URL
        break;
    case MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited:
        NSLog(@"User Exited");
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

or add a custom function for check the request timeout ..

```
[self performSelector:@selector(checkTimeout:) withObject:theMovie afterDelay:15];
```

if you are not receiving any `Notification` in your code 
please check this answer for further reference .[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190790/1721884)

Comment: Thanks, and great answer.  In my case, we have a situation where we have 5 servers behind a load-balancer.  Occasionally a few of those servers will return 404's, while the others return 200's. If I attempt to fetch the manifest/video (HLS) prior to the video player doing it, then it is not a guarantee that the next request by the player will succeed. Obviously we are trying to fix the server-side issue, but it would be ideal for the client to handle the situation gracefully as well.  I never seem receive a notification of the playback ending...

Comment: you can add a request timeout  .. using a custom function ..
or use something similar to this .. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5869448/1721884) or [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7659735/1721884)

Comment: @Steve : if the above answer didn't work for you .
try using `ffmpeg` or `AVFoundation`. will try it my self before changing my answer .. try edit your question by explaining the backend problem ..

Comment: The timeout timer is a good suggestion.  I will go that route a see how that goes.  Thanks.